# Замена текста TextView в Layout который открывается при нажатии на элемент с RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, textview

У меня есть `RecyclerView` в Layout, и при нажатии на любой элемент в `RecyclerView` открываться другой Layout где есть `TextView` мне нужно в нем подменять текст.

Пробовал делать в адаптере `RecyclerView` так:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SubCategory.mName.clear();
                SubCategory.onSelectSubCategory(position);
                TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.name_sub_category);
                textView.setText(mName.get(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SubCategory.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click to " + position + " position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kz.sferagroup.fromcaappication, PID: 624
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:173)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:747)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
        at kz.sferagroup.fromcaappication.SubCategory.onSelectSubCategory(SubCategory.java:56)
        at kz.sferagroup.fromcaappication.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter$1.onClick(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:48)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7297)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7274)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:819)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28023)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже разобрался во всем!
View при нажатии может работать только с теми элементами, которые есть в его Layout. И не получится заметить в другом Layout.

Для этого я в статичную переменную переменную в класс относящийся к нужному Layout передал текст. И после этого  уже заменил его в нем.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы немного путаете. Скорее всего под `Layout` вы имеете в виду активити. Если да, и вы передаёте в неё данные через статическую переменную - то это неправильно. Используйте Intent и его методы `putExtra`